# Cannot install MySQL server in WIndows XP

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-xp

I'm trying to install MySQL in my computer but I keep getting this error all the time:

[image]

[image]

I uninstalled like 8 times already, any help would be very appreciated.
I searched about this in Google but any solution solve my problem.

The firewall is disabled and already have the exception for the port `3306`, but still the error keeps coming :

[image]
[image]
[image]

**EDIT:**
I follow the advices and stills could not connect in my database:

[image]

Here's the select of the user in database, the password is the same for all of them as you can see:

[image]

And it looks I can `ping` but still getting the error in connection:
[image]

**EDIT 2:**
After create the users and try to connect using them :

```
    C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>mysql --user=root --password  mysql
Enter password: *********
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 9
Server version: 5.5.22 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> create user 'valter'@'localhost' identified by 'greyfox';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> grant all privileges on *.* 'valter'@'localhost' with grant option;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''val
er'@'localhost' with grant option' at line 1
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'valter'@'localhost' with grant option;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create user 'valter'@'%' identified by 'greyfox';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'valter'@'%' with grant option;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create user 'admin'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> grant reload process on *.* to 'admin'@'localhost';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'proc
ss on *.* to 'admin'@'localhost'' at line 1
mysql> grant reload, process on *.* to 'admin'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create user 'dummy'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select User, Host from mysql.user;
+--------+-----------+
| User   | Host      |
+--------+-----------+
| valter | %         |
| root   | 127.0.0.1 |
| root   | ::1       |
|        | localhost |
| admin  | localhost |
| dummy  | localhost |
| root   | localhost |
| valter | localhost |
+--------+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: *********
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 5.5.22 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select User, Host from mysql.user;
+--------+-----------+
| User   | Host      |
+--------+-----------+
| valter | %         |
| root   | 127.0.0.1 |
| root   | ::1       |
|        | localhost |
| admin  | localhost |
| dummy  | localhost |
| root   | localhost |
| valter | localhost |
+--------+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

And when I try to connect using the Heidi gives the same error:

[image]

**EDIT 3:**

Here it goes some queries I'm making to find out what is this error :

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>mysqladmin -u root -p version
Enter password: *********
mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.5.22, for Win32 on x86
Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Server version          5.5.22
Protocol version        10
Connection              localhost via TCP/IP
TCP port                3306
Uptime:                 7 hours 8 min 31 sec

Threads: 2  Questions: 43  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 39  Flush tables: 1  Open tab
les: 0  Queries per second avg: 0.001

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>
```

Another command:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>mysqladmin -u root -p -h 'localhost' version variables;
Enter password: *********
mysqladmin: connect to server at ''localhost'' failed
error: 'Unknown MySQL server host ''localhost'' (0)'
Check that mysqld is running on 'localhost' and that the port is 3306.
You can check this by doing 'telnet 'localhost' 3306'


C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>mysqladmin -h `localhost` --port=3306 ve
rsion
mysqladmin: connect to server at '`localhost`' failed
error: 'Unknown MySQL server host '`localhost`' (0)'
Check that mysqld is running on `localhost` and that the port is 3306.
You can check this by doing 'telnet `localhost` 3306'
```

And this is `my.ini` file:

```
# MySQL Server Instance Configuration File
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated by the MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard
#
#
# Installation Instructions
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# On Linux you can copy this file to /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options
# (@localstatedir@ for this installation) or to
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# On Windows you should keep this file in the installation directory 
# of your server (e.g. C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y). To
# make sure the server reads the config file use the startup option 
# "--defaults-file". 
#
# To run run the server from the command line, execute this in a 
# command line shell, e.g.
# mysqld --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y\my.ini"
#
# To install the server as a Windows service manually, execute this in a 
# command line shell, e.g.
# mysqld --install MySQLXY --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y\my.ini"
#
# And then execute this in a command line shell to start the server, e.g.
# net start MySQLXY
#
#
# Guildlines for editing this file
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that the program supports.
# If you want to know the options a program supports, start the program
# with the "--help" option.
#
# More detailed information about the individual options can also be
# found in the manual.
#
#
# CLIENT SECTION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# The following options will be read by MySQL client applications.
# Note that only client applications shipped by MySQL are guaranteed
# to read this section. If you want your own MySQL client program to
# honor these values, you need to specify it as an option during the
# MySQL client library initialization.
#
[client]

port=3306

[mysql]

default-character-set=latin1


# SERVER SECTION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# The following options will be read by the MySQL Server. Make sure that
# you have installed the server correctly (see above) so it reads this 
# file.
#
[mysqld]

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306


#Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
basedir="C:/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/"

#Path to the database root
datadir="C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Dados de aplicativos/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/Data/"

# The default character set that will be used when a new schema or table is
# created and no character set is defined
character-set-server=latin1

# The default storage engine that will be used when create new tables when
default-storage-engine=INNODB

# Set the SQL mode to strict
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

# The maximum amount of concurrent sessions the MySQL server will
# allow. One of these connections will be reserved for a user with
# SUPER privileges to allow the administrator to login even if the
# connection limit has been reached.
max_connections=100

# Query cache is used to cache SELECT results and later return them
# without actual executing the same query once again. Having the query
# cache enabled may result in significant speed improvements, if your
# have a lot of identical queries and rarely changing tables. See the
# "Qcache_lowmem_prunes" status variable to check if the current value
# is high enough for your load.
# Note: In case your tables change very often or if your queries are
# textually different every time, the query cache may result in a
# slowdown instead of a performance improvement.
query_cache_size=0

# The number of open tables for all threads. Increasing this value
# increases the number of file descriptors that mysqld requires.
# Therefore you have to make sure to set the amount of open files
# allowed to at least 4096 in the variable "open-files-limit" in
# section [mysqld_safe]
table_cache=256

# Maximum size for internal (in-memory) temporary tables. If a table
# grows larger than this value, it is automatically converted to disk
# based table This limitation is for a single table. There can be many
# of them.
tmp_table_size=9M


# How many threads we should keep in a cache for reuse. When a client
# disconnects, the client's threads are put in the cache if there aren't
# more than thread_cache_size threads from before.  This greatly reduces
# the amount of thread creations needed if you have a lot of new
# connections. (Normally this doesn't give a notable performance
# improvement if you have a good thread implementation.)
thread_cache_size=8

#*** MyISAM Specific options

# The maximum size of the temporary file MySQL is allowed to use while
# recreating the index (during REPAIR, ALTER TABLE or LOAD DATA INFILE.
# If the file-size would be bigger than this, the index will be created
# through the key cache (which is slower).
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G

# If the temporary file used for fast index creation would be bigger
# than using the key cache by the amount specified here, then prefer the
# key cache method.  This is mainly used to force long character keys in
# large tables to use the slower key cache method to create the index.
myisam_sort_buffer_size=17M

# Size of the Key Buffer, used to cache index blocks for MyISAM tables.
# Do not set it larger than 30% of your available memory, as some memory
# is also required by the OS to cache rows. Even if you're not using
# MyISAM tables, you should still set it to 8-64M as it will also be
# used for internal temporary disk tables.
key_buffer_size=10M

# Size of the buffer used for doing full table scans of MyISAM tables.
# Allocated per thread, if a full scan is needed.
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K

# This buffer is allocated when MySQL needs to rebuild the index in
# REPAIR, OPTIMZE, ALTER table statements as well as in LOAD DATA INFILE
# into an empty table. It is allocated per thread so be careful with
# large settings.
sort_buffer_size=256K


#*** INNODB Specific options ***


# Use this option if you have a MySQL server with InnoDB support enabled
# but you do not plan to use it. This will save memory and disk space
# and speed up some things.
#skip-innodb

# Additional memory pool that is used by InnoDB to store metadata
# information.  If InnoDB requires more memory for this purpose it will
# start to allocate it from the OS.  As this is fast enough on most
# recent operating systems, you normally do not need to change this
# value. SHOW INNODB STATUS will display the current amount used.
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M

# If set to 1, InnoDB will flush (fsync) the transaction logs to the
# disk at each commit, which offers full ACID behavior. If you are
# willing to compromise this safety, and you are running small
# transactions, you may set this to 0 or 2 to reduce disk I/O to the
# logs. Value 0 means that the log is only written to the log file and
# the log file flushed to disk approximately once per second. Value 2
# means the log is written to the log file at each commit, but the log
# file is only flushed to disk approximately once per second.
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

# The size of the buffer InnoDB uses for buffering log data. As soon as
# it is full, InnoDB will have to flush it to disk. As it is flushed
# once per second anyway, it does not make sense to have it very large
# (even with long transactions).
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M

# InnoDB, unlike MyISAM, uses a buffer pool to cache both indexes and
# row data. The bigger you set this the less disk I/O is needed to
# access data in tables. On a dedicated database server you may set this
# parameter up to 80% of the machine physical memory size. Do not set it
# too large, though, because competition of the physical memory may
# cause paging in the operating system.  Note that on 32bit systems you
# might be limited to 2-3.5G of user level memory per process, so do not
# set it too high.
innodb_buffer_pool_size=17M

# Size of each log file in a log group. You should set the combined size
# of log files to about 25%-100% of your buffer pool size to avoid
# unneeded buffer pool flush activity on log file overwrite. However,
# note that a larger logfile size will increase the time needed for the
# recovery process.
innodb_log_file_size=10M

# Number of threads allowed inside the InnoDB kernel. The optimal value
# depends highly on the application, hardware as well as the OS
# scheduler properties. A too high value may lead to thread thrashing.
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
```

Comment: It looks like the MySQL service itself is starting, but the script which applies security settings can't connect. Try using the command line to connect to the database yourself. If it works, you know the MySQL server itself is running. Then you can just run `mysql_secure_installation` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-secure-installation.html) to secure it.

Comment: Which version of mysql is this? I recall seeing errors like this in some pervious versions, but was able to just configure it using MySQL workbench instead of the installer.

Comment: The version is `mysql-5.5.22-win32`

Comment: @LoganBibby I update my post, could you please take a look ?

Comment: I went ahead and posted it as an answer since it was a pretty lengthy walk through. Feel free to post on it for any clarification!

Comment: Have another service with port 3306 open?

Comment: @GabrielSantos, no I don't have another service using the port 3306.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you install MySQL with the default settings (provide more details if not). So check your **firewall** if the port for MySQL is open.

The default port is 3306. If that doesn't solve your problem, here is the MySQL Documentation on this error:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Answer (score 0):

The installation looks like it's completing. The last step just does some finishing touches...

First, check to see if MySQL installed. Go to your *Programs and Features* section of the Control Panel. Scroll through (or use the search feature) to look for the `MySQL Server 5.5` program.

If it's installed, make sure the service was added and started properly. Open the Services window by typing into the Run prompt `services.msc`. It lists all of your services. Depending on what the service was named (probably just `MySQL`), scroll through and look for it in that list. Make sure it says `Started` in the *Status* column.

If it's installed and the service is started, then you know the database installed properly. More than likely, it's just something in the installer that's causing it to break. (Which is good, means you're doing nothing wrong!)

To secure the installation, you can try manually running the included script. But, all it does it take the information you gave during the first steps of the installer and apply them.

According to the [script's documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-secure-installation.html), it sets the `root` password, removes `root` access privileges to anything but `localhost`, removes anonymous user accounts, and removes test databases. So, you can do that all yourself.

Comment: I check and is installed properly and the services is set correctly too.

Comment: Good! Then you can just made the appropriate security changes and you'll be good to go! :) If you're not sure how to do all the things to secure your install, check out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html

Comment: I follow your advices but still could not connect in my database, please take a look in the new picture in my thread.

Comment: A ping won't tell you whether or not your database is accessible, as you can't ping a particular port. Since the computer you're working on is located on your network, add a user via command line that can access it from within your network (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html). Then use something like HeidiSQL (http://www.heidisql.com/) to connect to it from your PC (versus the remote host) to eliminate any privileges issues.

Comment: I did all the things that you recommend me to, but still receiving this error.

Comment: ...So you get the error when attempting to access the database using HeidiSQL from your local PC?

Comment: can you do a telnet on the mysql port of your localhost  like    telnet localhost 3306